# Como hacer que la tabla no se deforme al mostrar mas de 4 tablas dentro de el?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla que muestra dentro de el tablas con resultados, el problema es que a medida que van incrementando las tablas, la tabla padre se va alargando horizontalmente obviamente, como hago para que aunque vaya incrementando las tablas resultado esta se mantenga horizontal si que se alargue? les muestro:

esto es lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la unica manera que logro para que esto se vea asi es reduciendo el tamano de las fuentes y de los padding, al incrementar algo eso se me deforma, quedandome esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede solucionar con algo de los contenedores padre o inline block, pero soy malisimo para el css xDDD, estoy jugando con los valores de los contenedores pero nada que funciona, aqui les dejo el codigo:

vista:

```
<div id="see_actual_products">
       <div class="see_actual_products">
            <div id="products">
                <h1 v-if="showProducts == true">{{message}}</h1>
            </div>
            <table id="table_container_actual_products" v-if = "showProducts == false">
                <tr>
                    <th>Current products in production.</th>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id ="table_actual_products" v-for="i in listCurrentproducts">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Room: {{i.room}}</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>Name: {{i.name}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>LOT: {{i.lot}}</td>
                            </tr>    
                            <tr>    
                                <td>Quantity to be package: {{i.quantity_to_package}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>Quantity of pallets: {{i.pallets}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>Progress: {{i.progress}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{i.finished_pallets}} pallets of {{i.pallets}} pallets
                                    <button @click="addPallet(i.room)">Add Pallet</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-if="i.pallets == i.finished_pallets">
                                <td>
                                    <h3>Completed</h3>
                                    <button @click="finish(i.room)">Finish procedure</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>    
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </div>
```

css:

```
#see_actual_products{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

.see_actual_products {
    display: inline-block;
}

#table_container_actual_products {
    display:inline-block; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 149, 144, 0.8);
    border: 8px groove #72d3c6;
    padding:5px 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#table_container_actual_product, th{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #216e64;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#table_actual_products {
    float:left; 
    margin: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #216e64; 
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#table_actual_products, td{   
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
    padding: 5px;
}


#table_actual_products {
    text-align: center;
}

#table_actual_products button{
    color:black;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #8cdbd7;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#table_actual_products button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
}
```

muchas gracias :)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que dependiendo del tamaño del `div` es cuando se va a "deformar", si el tamaño de los elementos es  mayor el ancho del `div` obviamente se va a deformar. `width` cambia el ancho del `div`.

Comment: pero en ningun momento modifico su witdh ya que no hay muchos valores que asignar si porngo 100% este toma toda la pantalla, asi que no se de verdad, sigo probando pero lo que mas me fastidia es eso, que se deforma al incrementar el tamano de las letras o si son mas de 4 y el div padre no aguanta

Comment: Yo creo que para estos casos es mejor usar `grid` o `flex`, así puedes tener un mayor control de la visualización.